# Is it possible to change the drive letter of the Azure Temporary Storage Drive?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I have a new VM instance in Azure, and by default it comes with C: and D:. I understand that D: is volatile and can be lost at some points.

My application uses drive D: as a working drive though, and stores all my the utilities and process output files there.

I've attached a new drive, but it's F:. Is there any way to change the drive letters so that my attached drive is D: and the temporary one is anything else?

Comment: Quick update - I changed the paging file to C:, then I was able to swap the drive letters of D: and F:, then move the paging file back to F: (now the temporary drive). Are there any potential implications of doing this?

Comment: Can populate some data in each of the drives and then restart the server instance (reboot). The data drive should hold on to the info and ephemeral drive will obviously lose the data. If it works for data consistency and drive letter consistency, I guess you are good to go.

Comment: On a different note, if you could work on your application to use any drive (make it configurable instead of D: hard-coded) there is nothing best like that. You need not worry about all the above intricacies.

Comment: Thanks Naveen - will try it out, but it seems to be stable for now. Ideally changing the app to be more flexible would be better, but unfortunately that's not up to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things what you can do is change the drive letters. You can do it under Server Manager -> Storage Manager -> Pick The Drive -> Change Drive Letter and Path. There can you can change the drive letters.

The litmus test what can perform is rebooting the server and checking for the consistency of the drive letters and data in the additional data disk. Ephemeral disk's data will be gone.

However with the above things in place, there is nothing like modifying your application to use any drive (unlike D: in you case). With that you need to worry about the moving parts and their uncertainty.

Comment: The problem is that by default the page file is on D:, so you have to move it before it lets you change letters. I did that and it seems to work

Answer (score 1):

We have recently updated Azure VMs so the temp drive letter will be maintained regardless of which drive letter is used. So you can set the temp drive letter to something like T: or Z:, and it will be maintained through stop/start operations or Azure healing operations which used to cause the drive letter to reset back to the first available drive letter. This change applies to both Classic and ARM virtual machines.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying you're on the team that maintains Azure? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, there is now an official document describing this process.
The pagefile.sys file has to be relocated to the new drive by temporarily moving it to C: first.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/change-drive-letter